# Python - RegEx - False imbrication of comments

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing some mans with a python script and I'm trying to exclude all the text that's commented. So I thought about regex and made the following bit of code :

```
text = re.sub(r' (?s)/\*(.*)\*/', "", text)
```

At first everything seemed to work fine unfortunately what it does isn't exactly what I thought it would do :

Initial text :

```
some text 1
/* a comment */
some text 2
/* a comment */
some text 3
```

My expected result was :

```
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
```

But it actually is :

```
some text 1
some text 3
```

Instead of removing the to occurrences of

```
/* comment */
```

it removed from the first /* to the last */ so :

```
/* comment */
some text 2
/* comment */
```

How can I fix it so it removes each occurrences instead of a big chunk of interesting text?

Comment: Use lazy matching `r'(?s)/\*(.*?)\*/'`

Comment: again a `greedy` one..also remove space in your `regex` from intial